# unable to increment values by one inside of the label using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-4, codeigniter-3

i'm dynamically adding fields. whenever fields newly created i just want to show the input field or a label field number.
suppose if click to add new field dynamically which is should call 1 if appear second then should call 2.
i had tried some logic over there in my coding but doesn't working.

```js
$(function() {
 /*here my values to increment whenever added newly form */
  var i = 1;
  i++;
  var max_fields = 6;
  var this_button_work_for_click_to_add_rooms = $(".this_button_work_for_click_to_add_rooms");
  var this_is_field_wrapper = $(".this_is_field_wrapper");
  var add_fields = '<div><div class="row"><div class="form-group"><div class="col-xs-1"><h6>Options -</h6><h6 class="#">Adults(12+)</h6><select id="selected_adults[]" name="selected_adults[]" class="form-control"><option   value="1">1</option><option selected="selected" value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option></select></div><!-- </div><div class="form-group"> --><div class="col-xs-1"><h6>'+i+' Room</h6><h6 class="m_label">Child(0-12)</h6><select id="selected_childs[]" name="selected_childs[]" onchange="displayingNumberOfChildAge(this);" class="form-control"><option>select</option><option id="first_child_col"  value="1">1</option><option id="second_child_col"  value="2">2</option></select></div><!-- </div><div class="form-group"> --><div class="col-xs-1"><h6>optional</h6><h6 class="m_label">Child(1)Age</h6><select  class="form-control" id="selected_childs_age_group_one[]" name="selected_childs_age_group_one[]"><option  value="1">1</option><option  value="2">2</option><option  value="3">3</option><option  value="4">4</option><option  value="5">5</option><option  value="6">6</option><option  value="7">7</option><option  value="8">8</option><option  value="9">9</option><option  value="10">10</option><option  value="11">11</option><option  value="12">12</option></select></div><!-- </div><div class="form-group"> --><div class="col-xs-1"><h6>optional</h6><h6 class="m_label">Child(2)Age</h6><select class="form-control" id="selected_childs_age_group_two[]" name="selected_childs_age_group_two[]"><option  value="1">1</option><option  value="2">2</option><option  value="3">3</option><option  value="4">4</option><option  value="5">5</option><option  value="6">6</option><option  value="7">7</option><option  value="8">8</option><option  value="9">9</option><option  value="10">10</option><option  value="11">11</option><option  value="12">12</option></select></div><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_input_button" title="Remove field">remove</a></div><!-- here ending form group --></div><!-- here ending row --></div>';
 
 
  //here we starting counting...
  var input_count=1;
  //add buttong dynamically over here...
  $(this_button_work_for_click_to_add_rooms).click(function(event) {
   /* Act on the event */
   if(input_count<max_fields){
    input_count++;
    $(this_is_field_wrapper).append(add_fields);
   }
  });
  $(this_is_field_wrapper).on('click','.remove_input_button',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).parent('div').remove();
   input_count--;
  });
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Welcome|Home</title>
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <!-- jQuery library -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="this_is_field_wrapper">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-xs-1">
                  <h6>Options -</h6>
                  <h6 class="#">Adults(12+)</h6>
                  <select id="selected_adults[]" name="selected_adults[]" class="form-control">
                     <option   value="1">1</option>
                     <option selected="selected" value="2">2</option>
                     <option value="3">3</option>
                     <option value="4">4</option>
                     <option value="5">5</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <!-- </div>
                  <div class="form-group"> -->
               <div class="col-xs-1">
                  <h6>1st Room</h6>
                  <h6 class="m_label">Child(0-12)</h6>
                  <select id="selected_childs[]" name="selected_childs[]" onchange="displayingNumberOfChildAge(this);" class="form-control">
                     <option>select</option>
                     <option id="first_child_col"  value="1">1</option>
                     <option id="second_child_col"  value="2">2</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <!-- </div>
                  <div class="form-group"> -->
               <div class="col-xs-1">
                  <h6>optional</h6>
                  <h6 class="m_label">Child(1)Age</h6>
                  <select  class="form-control" id="selected_childs_age_group_one[]" name="selected_childs_age_group_one[]">
                     <option  value="1">1</option>
                     <option  value="2">2</option>
                     <option  value="3">3</option>
                     <option  value="4">4</option>
                     <option  value="5">5</option>
                     <option  value="6">6</option>
                     <option  value="7">7</option>
                     <option  value="8">8</option>
                     <option  value="9">9</option>
                     <option  value="10">10</option>
                     <option  value="11">11</option>
                     <option  value="12">12</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <!-- </div>
                  <div class="form-group"> -->
               <div class="col-xs-1">
                  <h6>optional</h6>
                  <h6 class="m_label">Child(2)Age</h6>
                  <select class="form-control" id="selected_childs_age_group_two[]" name="selected_childs_age_group_two[]">
                     <option  value="1">1</option>
                     <option  value="2">2</option>
                     <option  value="3">3</option>
                     <option  value="4">4</option>
                     <option  value="5">5</option>
                     <option  value="6">6</option>
                     <option  value="7">7</option>
                     <option  value="8">8</option>
                     <option  value="9">9</option>
                     <option  value="10">10</option>
                     <option  value="11">11</option>
                     <option  value="12">12</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-1">
                  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="this_button_work_for_click_to_add_rooms" title="Add field">Click & Add Rooms</a>                      
               </div>
            </div>
            <!-- here ending form group -->
         </div>
         <!-- here ending row -->
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

As you can see whenever adding dynamically it is giving 2nd room. not increment the value nor showing values on that the fields.
please help 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are set on start and needs to be re-set? to change its value, you also were not incrementing "i" in your for loops but used it as a variable for the add_fields.

Try This

```
$(function() {
    /*here my values to increment whenever added newly form */
        var i = 1;
        i++;
        var max_fields = 6;
        var this_button_work_for_click_to_add_rooms = $(".this_button_work_for_click_to_add_rooms");
        var this_is_field_wrapper = $(".this_is_field_wrapper");



        //here we starting counting...
        var input_count=1;
        //add buttong dynamically over here...
        $(this_button_work_for_click_to_add_rooms).click(function(event) {
            /* Act on the event */
            if(input_count<max_fields){
                input_count++;
                var add_fields = '<div><div class="row"><div class="form-group"><div class="col-xs-1"><h6>Options -</h6><h6 class="#">Adults(12+)</h6><select id="selected_adults[]" name="selected_adults[]" class="form-control"><option   value="1">1</option><option selected="selected" value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option></select></div><!-- </div><div class="form-group"> --><div class="col-xs-1"><h6>'+input_count+' Room</h6><h6 class="m_label">Child(0-12)</h6><select id="selected_childs[]" name="selected_childs[]" onchange="displayingNumberOfChildAge(this);" class="form-control"><option>select</option><option id="first_child_col"  value="1">1</option><option id="second_child_col"  value="2">2</option></select></div><!-- </div><div class="form-group"> --><div class="col-xs-1"><h6>optional</h6><h6 class="m_label">Child(1)Age</h6><select  class="form-control" id="selected_childs_age_group_one[]" name="selected_childs_age_group_one[]"><option  value="1">1</option><option  value="2">2</option><option  value="3">3</option><option  value="4">4</option><option  value="5">5</option><option  value="6">6</option><option  value="7">7</option><option  value="8">8</option><option  value="9">9</option><option  value="10">10</option><option  value="11">11</option><option  value="12">12</option></select></div><!-- </div><div class="form-group"> --><div class="col-xs-1"><h6>optional</h6><h6 class="m_label">Child(2)Age</h6><select class="form-control" id="selected_childs_age_group_two[]" name="selected_childs_age_group_two[]"><option  value="1">1</option><option  value="2">2</option><option  value="3">3</option><option  value="4">4</option><option  value="5">5</option><option  value="6">6</option><option  value="7">7</option><option  value="8">8</option><option  value="9">9</option><option  value="10">10</option><option  value="11">11</option><option  value="12">12</option></select></div><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_input_button" title="Remove field">remove</a></div><!-- here ending form group --></div><!-- here ending row --></div>';
                $(this_is_field_wrapper).append(add_fields);
            }
        });
        $(this_is_field_wrapper).on('click','.remove_input_button',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            input_count--;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try This:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Welcome|Home</title>
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <!-- jQuery library -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>

      <div class="this_is_field_wrapper">
         <div class="row item">
            <div class="form-group">
               <div class="col-xs-1">
                  <h6>Options -</h6>
                  <h6 class="#">Adults(12+)</h6>
                  <select id="selected_adults[]" name="selected_adults[]" class="form-control">
                     <option   value="1">1</option>
                     <option selected="selected" value="2">2</option>
                     <option value="3">3</option>
                     <option value="4">4</option>
                     <option value="5">5</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <!-- </div>
                  <div class="form-group"> -->
               <div class="col-xs-1">
                  <h6><span class="room_no">1</span> st Room</h6>
                  <h6 class="m_label">Child(0-12)</h6>
                  <select id="selected_childs[]" name="selected_childs[]" onchange="displayingNumberOfChildAge(this);" class="form-control">
                     <option>select</option>
                     <option id="first_child_col"  value="1">1</option>
                     <option id="second_child_col"  value="2">2</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <!-- </div>
                  <div class="form-group"> -->
               <div class="col-xs-1">
                  <h6>optional</h6>
                  <h6 class="m_label">Child(1)Age</h6>
                  <select  class="form-control" id="selected_childs_age_group_one[]" name="selected_childs_age_group_one[]">
                     <option  value="1">1</option>
                     <option  value="2">2</option>
                     <option  value="3">3</option>
                     <option  value="4">4</option>
                     <option  value="5">5</option>
                     <option  value="6">6</option>
                     <option  value="7">7</option>
                     <option  value="8">8</option>
                     <option  value="9">9</option>
                     <option  value="10">10</option>
                     <option  value="11">11</option>
                     <option  value="12">12</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <!-- </div>
                  <div class="form-group"> -->
               <div class="col-xs-1">
                  <h6>optional</h6>
                  <h6 class="m_label">Child(2)Age</h6>
                  <select class="form-control" id="selected_childs_age_group_two[]" name="selected_childs_age_group_two[]">
                     <option  value="1">1</option>
                     <option  value="2">2</option>
                     <option  value="3">3</option>
                     <option  value="4">4</option>
                     <option  value="5">5</option>
                     <option  value="6">6</option>
                     <option  value="7">7</option>
                     <option  value="8">8</option>
                     <option  value="9">9</option>
                     <option  value="10">10</option>
                     <option  value="11">11</option>
                     <option  value="12">12</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-1">
                  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="this_button_work_for_click_to_add_rooms" title="Add field">Click & Add Rooms</a>                         
               </div>
            </div>
            <!-- here ending form group -->
         </div>
         <!-- here ending row -->
      </div>


   </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
   $(function() {



      //add buttong dynamically over here...
      $('.this_button_work_for_click_to_add_rooms').click(function(event) {
         var numItems = $('.item').length;
         var count = numItems +1;

         var add_fields = '<div><div class="row item"><div class="form-group"><div class="col-xs-1"><h6>Options -</h6><h6 class="#">Adults(12+)</h6><select id="selected_adults[]" name="selected_adults[]" class="form-control"><option   value="1">1</option><option selected="selected" value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option></select></div><!-- </div><div class="form-group"> --><div class="col-xs-1"><h6><span class="room_no">'+count+'</span> Room</h6><h6 class="m_label">Child(0-12)</h6><select id="selected_childs[]" name="selected_childs[]" onchange="displayingNumberOfChildAge(this);" class="form-control"><option>select</option><option id="first_child_col"  value="1">1</option><option id="second_child_col"  value="2">2</option></select></div><!-- </div><div class="form-group"> --><div class="col-xs-1"><h6>optional</h6><h6 class="m_label">Child(1)Age</h6><select  class="form-control" id="selected_childs_age_group_one[]" name="selected_childs_age_group_one[]"><option  value="1">1</option><option  value="2">2</option><option  value="3">3</option><option  value="4">4</option><option  value="5">5</option><option  value="6">6</option><option  value="7">7</option><option  value="8">8</option><option  value="9">9</option><option  value="10">10</option><option  value="11">11</option><option  value="12">12</option></select></div><!-- </div><div class="form-group"> --><div class="col-xs-1"><h6>optional</h6><h6 class="m_label">Child(2)Age</h6><select class="form-control" id="selected_childs_age_group_two[]" name="selected_childs_age_group_two[]"><option  value="1">1</option><option  value="2">2</option><option  value="3">3</option><option  value="4">4</option><option  value="5">5</option><option  value="6">6</option><option  value="7">7</option><option  value="8">8</option><option  value="9">9</option><option  value="10">10</option><option  value="11">11</option><option  value="12">12</option></select></div><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_input_button" title="Remove field">remove</a></div><!-- here ending form group --></div><!-- here ending row --></div>';


         $(".this_is_field_wrapper").append(add_fields);

      });

      $('.this_is_field_wrapper').on('click','.remove_input_button',function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).closest('div.item').remove();
         numberRows();
      });

      function numberRows() {
         $('.room_no').each(function(i) {
         $(this).text(i + 1);
         console.log(i);
         });
      }
   });
</script>
```

Comment: My Pleasure. Happy coding.